# Why is this question off-topic?

Tags: discussion

I posted [this question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14024/msi-motherboards-for-pcie-4-0-gpu) and it got closed by [ArtOfCode](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/8/artofcode) because of the following reason:

> Technical support request — Questions asking about troubleshooting
> hardware or technical support for hardware are off-topic for Hardware
> Recommendations because the site is here to provide pre-purchase
> hardware recommendations and to recommend hardware for a specific
> task, rather than to support existing devices. You may get help on
> Super User.

I am requesting suggestions for a motherboard for a new configuration that I am building. I don't understand where the "Support Existing Devices" part comes into play. The admin saw the first sentence

> I am updating my tower and I was hoping I could get some guidance on a couple of questions.

And assumed it was asking for support on existing device? I am buying all new components. I am building a new system on an old case, old Power Supply, old storage, keyboard, and old mouse, but NONE OF THESE are the problem. The problem pertains to all new parts I am purchasing and I am requesting suggestions on hardware that would be most compatible with my choices.

Is this question really off-topic? If so, could someone explain why?

Comment: Mods power trip. It's perfectly normal on this website. Some of them are closing questions or marking them as duplicate when there's  5-6 years old same thread. This comment will be deleted too despite it's on meta stack. You'll see.

Comment: @SmoothNeon Yeah I figured. I spoke to a few friends and figured out what I needed. This branch of SE should not exist if they just close questions that perfectly fit the rules of the forum. Pointless and irritating.